# ViewController slow load time

Tags: ios, core-animation

I am making a an app which has multiple view controllers, based on core animation. Now when I run the app for the first time, it takes a painful amount of time to navigate from one view controller to another, but once I have called all the pages, then navigation becomes very smooth, like it's expected to.

Any pointers for optimizing the load time between viewControllers would be helpful.

Here is the code for passing the view controller

```
[self presentViewController:response withPushDirection:@"fromBottom"];
```

Here is the method for presentViewController

```
- (void) presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController withPushDirection: (NSString *) direction {

    [CATransaction begin];

    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype = direction;
    transition.duration = 0.25f;
    transition.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    transition.removedOnCompletion = YES;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:@"transition"];



    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:NULL];

    [CATransaction commit];

}
```

Comment: Navigation from one view to another will never take **painful amount of time**, unless you try to load or fetch and pass some large amount of data before the navigation . So please improve your question pointing what you do there.

Comment: Updated with some relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

There's a very nice WWDC 2012 video that can teach you a lot:

[Up and Running: Making a Great Impression with Every Launch](http://developer.apple.com/itunes/?destination=adc.apple.com.16351493766)